mariadb: get values from another table in a trigger function
table entries
 CREATE TABLE `entries` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `node_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attrib_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `unique_id` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ENTRIES_UNIQUE_COMPOUND` (`unique_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `HAS_A_ATTRIBUTE` (`attrib_id`),
  KEY `HAS_A_NODE` (`node_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ATTRIBUTE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attrib_id`) REFERENCES `attribs` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_NODE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`node_id`) REFERENCES `nodes` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5547 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci


table nodes
CREATE TABLE `nodes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_seen` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `ts_nodes` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nodes_unique_idx` (`name`,`ts_nodes`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6734 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci


table changelog
CREATE TABLE `change_log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `node_name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `attribute_name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `old_value` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `new_value` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `action` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=603 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

trigger definition on table entries
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_entry_trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `entries`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
       
             INSERT INTO change_log(type, node_name, attribute_name, old_value, new_value, action, ts)

             VALUES('ENTRIES', NEW.node_id, NEW.attrib_id, NULL, NEW.value, 'CREATE', NOW());

           END

the trigger works so far as is inserts data in the change_log table, but instead of the "real" node names it only inserts the id's.
MariaDB [aix_registry_dev]> select * from change_log LIMIT 10;
+-----+---------+-----------+----------------+-----------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
| id  | type    | node_name | attribute_name | old_value | new_value | action | ts                  |
+-----+---------+-----------+----------------+-----------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
| 271 | ENTRIES | 6728      | 1085           | AIX       | NULL      | DELETE | 2024-06-04 13:21:13 |
| 272 | ENTRIES | 6728      | 1086           | 0         | NULL      | DELETE | 2024-06-04 13:21:13 |
| 273 | ENTRIES | 6728      | 1087           | 0         | NULL      | DELETE | 2024-06-04 13:21:13 |
| 274 | ENTRIES | 6728      | 1088           | 1         | NULL      | DELETE | 2024-06-04 13:21:13 |
| 275 | ENTRIES | 6728      | 1089           | 0         | NULL      | DELETE | 2024-06-04 13:21:13 |
| 276 | ENTRIES | 6728      | 1090           | 1         | NULL      | DELETE | 2024-06-04 13:21:13 |
| 277 | ENTRIES | 6728      | 1091           | 0         | NULL      | DELETE | 2024-06-04 13:21:13 |
| 278 | ENTRIES | 6728      | 1092           | 1         | NULL      | DELETE | 2024-06-04 13:21:13 |
| 279 | ENTRIES | 6728      | 1093           | 0         | NULL      | DELETE | 2024-06-04 13:21:13 |
| 280 | ENTRIES | 6728      | 1094           | 0         | NULL      | DELETE | 2024-06-04 13:21:13 |
+-----+---------+-----------+----------------+-----------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.000 sec)


this query on the nodes table will get the name by id.
MariaDB [aix_registry_dev]> select name  from nodes where id = 6728;
+----------------------+
| name                 |
+----------------------+
| KUG01115_WSAP_HA_LPM |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)


how to integrate this subquery into the trigger to get the node names instead of the id's?
i already tried DECLARE and SET variations but this rendered the trigger dysfunctional.

CREATE TRIGGER `insert_entry_trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `entries`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 DECLARE nodename varchar(256)
 SET nodename = (select name  from nodes where id = NEW.node_id)
       
             INSERT INTO change_log(type, node_name, attribute_name, old_value, new_value, action, ts)

             VALUES('ENTRIES', nodename, NEW.attrib_id, NULL, NEW.value, 'CREATE', NOW());

           END


Modify the trigger to get name from nodes rather than using NEW.node_id into the insert statement.
Try
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_entry_trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `entries`
 FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO change_log (type, 
                               node_name, 
                               attribute_name, 
                               old_value, 
                               new_value, 
                               action, 
                               ts
                               )

        VALUES ('ENTRIES', 
               ( SELECT name  FROM nodes where id = NEW.node_id),
                NEW.attrib_id, 
                NULL, 
                NEW.value, 
                'CREATE', 
                NOW()
               );

    END

